# Is read while write possible on AWS EFS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs, google-cloud-filestore

On **AWS EFS**, is it possible to read my file while still writing it?
Same question for Google Cloud ([Cloud Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/)). Thanks.

Comment: I'm not an NFS expert, so this is not an answer. I'm also assuming that you're talking about reads/writes on separate machines. In that case, I _believe_ that you will not immediately see data that's been written, because it will still be in the source machine's buffer cache. My understanding is that NFS v4 has a delegation mechanism to coordinate concurrent access to the same file, but [EFS does not support this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/limits.html#nfs4-unsupported-features).

Comment: In the link you posted it is wriiten:"All locks in Amazon EFS are advisory, which means that READ and WRITE operations do not check for conflicting locks before the operation is executed.". This means this "no support" enables read while write. Thanks! Any clue on Google Cloud?

Comment: Either you mean something different than I do when you say "read while write," or you are misinterpreting that doc. If all you care about is that one machine can read a file when it's being written by another, then sure, that works. **But the reader may not see what the writer has written**.